# Finding conformal map from a region with a slit to upper half plane

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation

> Find a conformal map from $F=\{z=x+iy\in\mathbb{C}:-\pi<y<\pi\}\setminus(-\infty,0]$ to the upper half plane $\mathbb{H}=\{z=x+iy\in\mathbb{C}:y>0\}$

To be honest, I never dealt with strips with slits before so I don't really have an idea where to start. The first idea that came to mind is maybe use the logarithm function (since its' principal branch is when we take $\mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,0]$. Other than that I don't know how to continue. What is the general way to think on such questions?

Answer (score 3):

It helps to draw a picture of the image of each conformal map you use until you "reach" the upper half plane. Then the composition of those maps will be a conformal map onto $\mathbb{H}$.

First note $\exp$ maps $F$ onto the slit plane $\mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,1]$. The transformation $z\mapsto -z$ maps $\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty, 1]$ onto $\mathbb{C}\setminus [-1,\infty)$. Translation by $+1$ maps $\mathbb{C}\setminus[-1,\infty)$ onto $\mathbb{C}\setminus[0,\infty)$. Finally, a square root map sends $\mathbb{C}\setminus [0,\infty)$ onto $\mathbb{H}$.

Comment: Can you point towards a very good reference (text or notes) that explains these standard algorithm of finding such a conformal map as in this question? I was reading Conway but his explanations seem incomplete to me.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how you see that $log(z)$ does that? I feel like if I seen that it does that then I would've solved it

Comment: I think Churchill and Brown's Complex Variables is a place to start for a reference. Additionally you can look at Schaum's Outlines.

Comment: @kobe Why is $arg(z)$ between $-\pi$ and $\pi$? I have some $z$ in $F$, so $z=x+iy$ with $-\pi<y<\pi$ and $x\not\in (-\infty,0]$. I look at $\log(z)=\log|z|+iarg(z)$ but I don't know anything about $arg(z)$. Moreover, how does the slit come into account in your solutions?

Comment: Hi @GBA, I've made corrections.

Comment: Book:  *Conformal Mapping*, L. Bieberbach.  1953, 1964.  Reprinted by AMS: 2000, 2015.